# PHP DOM Parser Get Specific text by Class While Looping

Tags: php, html, dom

I am working on a PHP Simple DOM Parser and i want a simple solution for my question

```
<tr>
<td class="one">1</td>
<td class="two">2</td>
<td class="three">3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td class="one">10</td>
<td class="two">20</td>
<td class="three">30</td>
</tr>...
```

the html of mine is will look similar to the above

and i am looping over through **td** something like this

```
foreach ($sample->find("td") as $ele) 
            { 
                if($ele->class == "one")
                 echo "ONE = ".$ele->plaintext;
                if($ele->class == "two")
                 echo "TWO= ".$ele->plaintext;
            }
```

But is there any simple solution that without if condition getting the plaintext of particular class i dont want shorthand if also
I am expecting something like this below

```
$ele->class->one
```

Comment: Use an `XPath` expression …?

Comment: sorry i do no about that but i will see to it CBroe and i will get back to you

Answer (score 0):

take a look at it:

```
<?php

$html = "
   <table>
       <tr>
            <td class='one'>1</td>
            <td class='two'>2</td>
            <td class='three'>3</td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
            <td class='one'>10</td>
            <td class='two'>20</td>
            <td class='three'>30</td>
        </tr>
    </table>
";

// Your class name
$classeName = 'one';

$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadHTML($html);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);

// Get the results
$results = $xpath->query("//*[@class='" . $classeName . "']");
for($i=0; $i < $results->length; $i++) {
    echo $review = $results->item($i)->nodeValue . "<br>";
}



?>
```