# Simple DomDocument and GetElementsByTagName

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

I'm trying to parse a webpage for the ISBN number, the HTML looks like:

```
<tr>
            <td>ISBN: </td>
            <td itemprop="isbn">9781472223821</td>
        </tr>
```

I currently have:

```
header('Content-Type:application/json');
$url = "URL Removed";

$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, true);

$res = curl_exec($ch);

curl_close($ch);

$dom = new DomDocument();
@$dom->loadHTML($res);


$searchNodes = $dom->getElementsByTagName("//td[@itemprop='isbn']");

foreach ($searchNodes as $node) { 
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL; 
}
```

When i run this i get no output, i've double checked the xpath query in the chrome dev tools and that correctly selects the element i'm after.  i believe its something to do with teh nodeValue option. I've tried a var_dump on the $searchNode variable and get

object(DOMNodeList)#2 (1) {
["length"]=>
int(0)
}

Is anyone able to highlight my next steps to investigate with this.

Comment: To use an xpath query, you would need to use [`DOMXPath`](https://www.php.net/manual/domxpath.query.php). [`getElementsByTagName`](https://www.php.net/manual/domdocument.getelementsbytagname.php), as the name implies, only finds elements by their tag name

Comment: can you add the url or is that secret? Does the curl request correctly return the HTML you expect? Is there Javascript at work here?

Comment: FYI, `echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL;` isn't going to produce valid JSON as per your earlier `header('Content-Type:application/json')` call

Comment: Also: https://stackoverflow.com/q/29061347/2943403

Answer (score -1):

`getElementsByTagName` expects only a single tag name. Here is a working example using [DOMXPath](https://www.php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php):

```php
$res = '
    <tr>
        <td>ISBN: </td>
        <td itemprop="isbn">9781472223821</td>
    </tr>
';

$dom = new DomDocument();
$dom->loadHTML($res);

$xpath = new DOMXPath($dom);
$searchNodes = $xpath->query("//td[@itemprop='isbn']");

foreach ($searchNodes as $node) { 
    echo $node->nodeValue, PHP_EOL; 
}
```

Comment: When a question in 2021 is basic, you can be very certain that it is a duplicate.  Please help us to close duplicate questions so that the Roomba can automatically remove redundant content.